# Firebase and android connectivity

Tags: android, firebase

I m trying to connect my android in windows 10 to firebase for online data storage but during authenticating my client ,i m facing problem.
when i am opening  the terminal in android studio and copying these lines:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

I am getting this message

> illegal option : **-allias

Please help.

[image: Error message in Android Studio]

Comment: Why is there a back-slash before `-alias`?  Try removing it.

Comment: It just worked.Back slash was the problem.Thanks.